# Passing value to JSP in spring

Tags: java, spring, modelandview

I have three tabs with href links,

```
<ul >
        <li class="active">
            <a href="#tab_0" id="tab1" data-toggle="tab">Search by Booking ID</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#tab_1" id="tab2" data-toggle="tab">Today's Booking</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#tab_2" id="tab3" data-toggle="tab">Search by Date</a>
        </li>
</ul>
```

When submitting the form in each tab, I'm passing a value to server to know which tab I've selected, using a hidden input field < input type=hidden value="tab1" id="view"/>. What I want is to get the same value on the jsp page and select the corresponding tab, on page load. I'm using Spring framework. I tried adding an additional object in ModelAndView, like

```
ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
model.addObject("view", view);
```

And script code is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       var activeTab = ${view};

       if(activeTab == "tab1"){
           $("#tab1").click();

       } else if(activeTab == "tab2"){
           $("#tab2").click();

       }else if(activeTab == "tab3"){
           $("#tab3").click();

       }else{
            $("#tab1").click();
       }
    });
```

But this is not working. :( Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `JavaScript` code. since you are already adding the `view` value in your response, you can use `el` just to enforce the `active` css class in your JSP file for the specified tab, like this

```
<ul >
    <li ${view eq "tab1"?'class="active"':''}>
        <a href="#tab_0" id="tab1" data-toggle="tab">Search by Booking ID</a>
    </li>
    <li ${view eq "tab2"?'class="active"':''}>
        <a href="#tab_1" id="tab2" data-toggle="tab">Today's Booking</a>
    </li>
    <li ${view eq "tab3"?'class="active"':''}>
        <a href="#tab_2" id="tab3" data-toggle="tab">Search by Date</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```